# How to prove that a set is recursively enumerable?

Tags: computer-science, recursion, computability

I was preparing for my "Theoretical Computer Science" exam and, while reviewing some old tests, I came across an exercise about recursively enumerable sets. My intuition was to try to exploit the property that says that the composition of partially computable functions is partially computable but couldn't figure out how to make it work in this case. What am I missing?

Here's the exercise:
Having a computable function $h(x)$ and a set $C = \{ x \space | \space h(x) \in D \}$, how would you prove that $C$ is recursively enumerable knowing that $D$ is recursively enumerable?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @AnotherUser Thank you for the info! I should've explained my thinking process in the post, I wanted to prove it by function composition but I had some difficulties in finding what to compose with $h$. The answer of Anne Bauval actually made the problem clear to me. Next time I'll try to give you guys some context!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f$ be a [partial computable function witnessing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computably_enumerable_set#Equivalent_formulations) $D$'s recursive enumerability. Then $f\circ h$ is a partial computable function witnessing $C$'s recursive enumerability.

Comment: Thank you! I was actually trying to prove it by function composition but couldn't point out that if $D$ is recursively enumerable then there must be a partial computable function $f$ that proves that $D$ is actually r.e. Now it's clear, thank you again!